VSCode "Error while fetching extensions" if run VSCode as another user
When I try to run VSCode as another user (in Windows 10),
I get an Error:
Error while fetching extensions. Failed to fetch

Log in Toggle Developer tools:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
workbench.desktop.main.js:35 ERR [network] #10: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery - error POST Failed to fetch
workbench.desktop.main.js:3070 Failed: Failed to fetch
at JWe.E (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/AlexFolder/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1318:39744)
at async JWe.C (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/AlexFolder/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1318:36805)
at async JWe.z (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/AlexFolder/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1318:33535)
at async JWe.getExtensions (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/AlexFolder/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1318:32701)
at async UXe.getExtensions (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/AlexFolder/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2428:14793)
at async vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/AlexFolder/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2428:38344

I have no problem if I run VSCode as the main user. I haven't had this problem until I installed version 1.93.1 of VSCode and the problem didn't disappear when I've returned to version 1.94.2
I've tried to clear AppData for the another user, and remove .vscode folder, it didn't help.
Also I've tried to run google chrome as the another user and install the extension from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. I've got the access to this site, but I couldn't install the extension.
There are no proxy for both users.
What can I do next?
